# Expose rest APIs with SpringMVC without authentication

Tags: spring-mvc

This is a legacy project which uses Shrio, SpringMVC and Hibernate. There is a new requirement to expose some rest APIs from it. The clients can call these rest APIs directly without any need for authentication.

Is it possible to directly expose the methods defined by SpringMVC and secured by Shiro as rest APIs without authentication?

Comment: What is forcing you to authenticate now? What security measure do you have in place? It's impossible to answer the question otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using token-based authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using spring security, you could do something like this

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <!-- define access for all RESTful resources -->
    <intercept-url pattern="YOUR_URL_PATTERN" access="permitAll"/>
</http>
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: i use shiro for the authentication instead of spring security. how should i configure it?